# Pretty-print object hierarchy in Java?

Tags: java, logging, io, object-graph

I'm working on a data analytics project where we are representing a lot of the basic entities you find in a language.  I'd like to find a better way to print out their object graphs though for debugging purposes though. So, for example, we might have:

```
Function: Average
Description: some description
Overload #1:
    parameter-set: paramset-a
        columns: 
           currency: string
           value: double
           scale: integer
    result-set: result-set-a
    preference: first-find
Overload #2: ...
Overload #3: ...
```

---

**My Question**

Let's say, in the above example, `Function` is my root object. Function has some attributes and a series of overloads, each with their own attributes and child objects.

***Is there a library that can help me to print the object graph under a root function, in a well-formatted way?***

PS: The above example is relatively trivial; in many of our cases, the object hierarchies are 6-10 levels deep, and that's when the real problem comes in.

Comment: Do the objects have attributes, some of which have child nodes you have to recurse into? When I've had to format data like this a simple recursive enumeration that has an indentation parameter that gets incremented at each level of recursion has always come in handy.

Comment: Yeah, they have attributes.  I was thinking along the same lines as you... Maybe like a "toString(int tabs)" function that I can call for each entity, and I just return the tabs + the normal toString() for the entity.  I was kinda hoping there's a library that prints out the attributes of each class though to avoid the extra code.

Comment: Well, I don't know of one. Maybe someone else will reply with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from perfect, but this question really deserves an answer.

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/jsonbeans is one way to *kind of* accomplish something like this. It converts arbitrary Java objects (without having to annotate the fields or anything) to JSON, and includes a pretty-printing method. It can do *approximately* what you are asking for.

Using this library, you can do something like this:

```
Json json = new Json();
System.out.println(json.prettyPrint(person));
```

For some example data, the output you might get looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Nate",
"age": 31,
"numbers": [
   {
      "name": "Home",
      "class": "com.example.PhoneNumber",
      "number": "206-555-1234"
   },
   {
      "name": "Work",
      "class": "com.example.PhoneNumber",
      "number": "425-555-4321"
   }
]
}
```